# NgTemplateOutlet doesn't work for me

Tags: templates, angular, polymer, angular2-template

Im trying to play around with the new NgTemplateOutlet. I have found and read about it here:

[NgTemplateOutlet example that doesn't work for me](http://5thingsangular.github.io/2016/04/18/issue-2.html)

I tried using the same sample in there, but I always get the same error:
Template parse errors: components on an embeded template: MyDir

I guess there is something not correct with the example or at least missing (or maybe im wrong but I did try everything I could think of for 3 hours)

What im aiming to achieve ultimatly once I have a working example with NgTemplateOutlet is to write the following in my component html:

```
<template is="dom-bind"></template>
```

If I write it as is, angular will just remove the entire template tag from the dom. The reason to why I need this is described in the following questetion which is already on stack over flow:
[using paper datatable in angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36864501/using-paper-datatable-in-angular2)

Comment: How is `NgTemplateOutlet` related to Polymer? Please add more code/html that demonstrates what you actually try to accomplish.

Comment: It doesn't, but the template tag does. The code would like to work is the one in the first sample that I linked to. I copied this cde to my applucaition and it didn't do anything. I would like to know if its incorrect

Comment: `<template is="dom-bind">` inside an Angular component can't work. Angular doesn't render `<template>` tags, it just processes them internally.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37676593/how-to-repeat-a-piece-of-html-multiple-times-without-ngfor-and-without-anoher-c/37676946#37676946 for  Plunker examples.

Comment: Look at this: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/3101-experimenting-with-dynamic-template-rendering-in-angular-2-rc-1.htm