# How can I repeat a piece of HTML multiple times without ngFor and without another @Component?

Tags: html, angular

I want to repeat a piece of HTML, multiple times in my template.

But I want it to be repeated at different places on my page. This means that `ngFor` is not the solution as the pieces would be repeated directly one after the other.

A 'working solution' would be to define a specific `@Component` for my repeated HTML, and do something like that :

```html
<p>Whatever html</p>
<my-repeated-html></my-repeated-html>
<h4>Whatever</h4>
<my-repeated-html></my-repeated-html>
```

But I find it overkill to create a dedicated component for doing something like that, it has no functional meaning and is only required by the HTML structure I want to set up.

Is there really nothing in ng2 template engine to allow me to define an "inner template" and use it wherever I need it in the current template?

Comment: I don't get why you think a component is overkill. If there is no logic a component is hardly more than the template and a selector. How can it be simpler?

Comment: For instance this could be simpler If I could define something like that
<template name="chunc"><div>The html I want repeated</div></template> and the reuse it where I want <template-use name="chunc"/>. (this does not exists, just an example). But I understand that the design of ng2 is to put it in a component, ok.

Comment: Only within the same component?

Comment: Yes, this has no need to be available to other components.

Comment: I added a Plunker to my answer.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

**update Angular 5**

`ngOutletContext` was renamed to `ngTemplateOutletContext`

See also https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#500-beta5-2017-08-29

**original**

The recently added [ngTemplateOutlet](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgTemplateOutlet-directive.html) might be what you want

```ts
<template [ngTemplateOutlet]="templateRefExpression" [ngOutletContext]="objectExpression"></template>
```

It can currently be used like

```ts
<template #templateRef>
    <pre>{{self | json }}</pre>
</template>

<template [ngTemplateOutlet]="templateRef"></template>
```

A template can also be passed to a child component to be rendered there

```ts
@Component({
  selector: 'some-child',
  providers: [],
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Child</h2>
<template [ngTemplateOutlet]="template" ></template>
<template [ngTemplateOutlet]="template" ></template>
    </div>
  `,
  directives: []
})
export class Child {
  @ContentChild(TemplateRef) template:TemplateRef;
}
```

to be used like

```ts
<some-child>
  <template>
    <pre>{{self | json }}</pre>
  </template>
</some-child>
```

[**stackblitz example**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-w68sgs?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Another [**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/ydGRs5VhbJz2yqdDTHpE?p=preview)
that uses data passed as

```ts
<template [ngTemplateOutlet]="..." [ngOutletContext]="templateData"
```

This way `ngOutletContext` can be used in the template like

```ts
<template let-image="image">
 {{image}}
```

where `image` is a property of `templateData`

If `$implicit` is used

```ts
<template [ngTemplateOutlet]="..." [ngOutletContext]="{$implicit: templateData}"
```

the `ngOutletContext` can be used in the template like

```ts
<template let-item>
 {{item}}
```

Comment: Currently trying in a Plunker. Couldn't make it work yet.

Comment: can't get the above solution working @GünterZöchbauer. I don't see anything being rendered

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer nothing gets rendered in your example Plunkers

Comment: it is possible to set template from file ?

Comment: No. A workaround is to build a component at runtime like explained in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34784778/equivalent-of-compile-in-angular-2/37044960#37044960

Comment: @ShashankVivek thanks a lot for migrating the Plunker to StackBlitz!

Answer (score 2):

```
<campaign-channels-list (onItemSelected)="_onItemSelected($event)" [customTemplate]="customTemplate" (onDragComplete)="_onDragComplete($event)" [items]="m_blockList"></campaign-channels-list>
        <template #customTemplate let-item>
            <a href="#" [attr.data-block_id]="item.blockID">
                <i class="fa {{item.blockFontAwesome}}"></i>
                <span>{{item.blockName}}</span>
                <i class="dragch fa fa-arrows-v"></i>
                <span class="lengthTimer hidden-xs"> 
                    {{item.length | FormatSecondsPipe}}
                </span>
            </a>
        </template>
```

and in rx component:

```
<div class="sortableList">
                    <li (click)="_onItemSelected(item, $event, i)" *ngFor="let item of m_items; let i = index" class="listItems list-group-item" [ngClass]="{'selectedItem': m_selectedIdx == i}">
                        <template [ngTemplateOutlet]="customTemplate" [ngOutletContext]="{$implicit: item}">
                        </template>
                    </li>
                </div>
```

pay attention to:

`[ngOutletContext]="{$implicit: item}"`

as well as

`<template #customTemplate let-item>`