# Angular2 ComponentResolver and ng-content not rendering

Tags: angular

I'm trying to use `ComponentResolver` and `ng-content` together, however, when the resolver builds the component the transcluded content is not rendered.

I'm using Angular2 RC3. I do know there is some upcoming changes coming to the `ComponentResolver` ( https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9467 ) that might affect this.

```js
import {
  Input, 
  Component, 
  OnInit, 
  ViewContainerRef, 
  ComponentResolver, 
  ViewChild 
} from '@angular/core';
```

```
/**
 * COLUMN
 */
@Component({
    selector: 'column-component',
    template: `
      <div style="border:1px solid green; padding:5px;display:block;">
        <b>column: {{label}}</b>
        <ng-content></ng-content>
      </div>`
})
export class ColumnComponent {
  @Input() label: sting = "";
}
```

```
/**
 * CELL
 */
@Component({
    selector: 'cell-component',
    template: '<b>cell component</b> <div #target></div>'
})
export class CellComponent {

  @ViewChild('target', {read: ViewContainerRef}) target;

  constructor(
    private componentResolver:ComponentResolver, 
    private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.componentResolver.resolveComponent(ColumnComponent).then((factory) => {
      let componentRef = this.target.createComponent(factory, 0, this.viewContainerRef.injector);
    });
  }
}
```

```
/**
 * TABLE
 */
@Component({
    selector: 'datatable',
    template: `
      <div #target style="border:1px solid blue;padding:5px;">
        <b>table component</b>
        <cell-component
           style="border:1px solid yellow;padding:5px;display:block">
         </cell-component>
      </div>
    `,
    directives: [ CellComponent ]
})
export class TableComponent {
}
```

```
/**
 * ROOOT APP
 */
@Component({
    selector: 'root-app',
    template: `
      <div style="border:1px solid red;padding:5px;">
        <datatable>
          <column-component [label]="'my label'">
            column content
          </column-component>
        </datatable>
      </div>
    `,
    directives: [ ColumnComponent, TableComponent ]
})
export class AppComponent {

}
```

*Current behavior:* The words 'column content' that are content of the `column-component` are never rendered.

*Expected behavior*:The inner content ( words "column content" ) of the `column-component` would render.

- Plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/9inB4yiXsFCLoVTxaPkz?p=preview
- Use case: https://github.com/swimlane/angular2-data-table/tree/templates

---

**UPDATE**

@GünterZöchbauer answered my orginial question ( THANKS! ), however, I applied a bit more logic and sadly it did not work. See updated plunkr:
 https://plnkr.co/edit/CsbmY6wePC3AWZlBDy34?p=preview

*Expected Results:* The cells would be repeated for each row and the value of the `row`'s `age` attribute would be transposed to each.

Comment: Please add a simple demo on the plunker

Comment: What markup is "Markup" from?

Comment: @yurzui added the plunkr.

Comment: What is the expected behavior?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer updated :)

Comment: What's the "inner content"? What should be rendered?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer updated. basically the words "column content"

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/0QQfy9KopsnTGlvbBPLO?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `<ng-content>` to intermediate components as well

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/PnxQfLycEGYxP0Bj3xKW?p=preview)

Comment: That was it but once I applied some more logic, it did not work...see: https://plnkr.co/edit/CsbmY6wePC3AWZlBDy34?p=preview

Comment: I can't add the Plunker from my phone, but in case you are using `<ng-content>` with `*ngFor`, this is not supported.

Comment: As I assumed, you try to use `<ng-content>` within `*ngFor`. I guess you might follow https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8563. As workaround you could use something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37676593/how-to-repeat-a-piece-of-html-multiple-times-without-ngfor-and-without-anoher-c/37676946#37676946