# Can we have two ng-content with same select attribute?

Tags: angular

```
<div class="main">
  <ng-content select="[body]"></ng-content>
</div>
<div class="main-copy">
  <ng-content select="[body]"></ng-content>
</div>
```

I am trying to copy the same content into main-copy but unfortunately it is not working.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**update Angular 5**

`ngOutletContext` was renamed to `ngTemplateOutletContext`

See also https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#500-beta5-2017-08-29

**original**

No, that's not supported.

Every element matching the selector will be projected to the first `<ng-content>`.

Perhaps [`ngTemplateOutlet`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgTemplateOutlet-directive.html) or [`ngForTemplate`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgFor-directive.html#!#ngForTemplate-anchor) is what you're looking for.

See also

- [How to repeat a piece of HTML multiple times without ngFor and without another @Component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37676593/how-to-repeat-a-piece-of-html-multiple-times-without-ngfor-and-without-anoher-c/37676946#37676946)

Comment: Can you provide me any snippet?

Comment: What about the answer I linked to?

Comment: Sorry but could not get that. I am using ng2-boostrap and second ng-content will be placed inside ng2-bootsrap modal. Please help

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to help. You can't have two `<ng-content>` with the same selectors. I don't know ng2-bootstrap.

Answer (score 5):

For future references, [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sfi2hc?file=app%2Ftest-component%2Ftest-component.component.html) is a working example of multiple transclusion which utilizes ngTemplateOutlet.

### Reference

- [reusable components ngTemplateOutlet](https://alligator.io/angular/reusable-components-ngtemplateoutlet/)