# Reuse some views in a component Angular 2+

Tags: angular, angularjs-directive

Sometimes I want to reuse some views (HTML code) in a component (but won't create new component). Somethings like this:

```
<div *ngIf="Fordestop">
    <div class="divdesktop"></div>
    #insert-my-reuse-div-here
</div>

<div *ngIf="ForMobile">
    <div class="divmobile"></div>
    #insert-my-reuse-div-here
</div>

<ng-template #my-reuse-div>
<!--My reuse view-->
</ng-template>
```

How can I do that in Angular?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to repeat a piece of HTML multiple times without ngFor and without another @Component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37676593/how-to-repeat-a-piece-of-html-multiple-times-without-ngfor-and-without-another)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reuse template HTML block in Angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51086407/how-to-reuse-template-html-block-in-angular)

Answer (score 1):

```html
<div *ngIf="Fordestop">
    <div class="divdesktop"></div>
    <template [ngTemplateOutlet]="my-reuse-div"></template>
</div>

<div *ngIf="ForMobile">
    <div class="divmobile"></div>
    <template [ngTemplateOutlet]="my-reuse-div"></template>
</div>

<ng-template #my-reuse-div>
<!--My reuse view-->
</ng-template>
```

---

You can also use `ngFor` in some cases. This will need an array with variables that change for each part.

https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf