# How to reuse template HTML block in Angular?

Tags: angular

Lets suppose we have html block in file:

```
<div id="text">Text</div>
```

How can I reuse this html code below in the same file, I mean something like this:

```
<re-use id="text"></re-use>
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 232, accepted):

I think you wanted to reuse the same html block again. If i understand you correctly, below code should help

```
<ng-template #MsgRef >
        {{ mycontent }}
</ng-template>
```

To reuse above block in the same template,

```
 <ng-template [ngTemplateOutlet]="MsgRef"></ng-template> //reuse any number of times
```

Comment: You can user ng-content to show the template instead

Comment: Any idea how to make this work _outside_ the component/template html that defines the ng-template ref?

Comment: This is great solution but somehow am not able to create more the 2 ng template on one component

Comment: For the first block (with content definition) to be shown as well, you may want to add `[ngIf]="true"` to it, e.g. `<ng-template #MsgRef [ngIf]="true">`

Comment: @Krishnan to use it in multiple components I would say extract that logic in a separate component.

Comment: this is not working for me it's throwing ```MsgRef``` not found

Answer (score 90):

Creating a new component is the most common way, but sometimes you only need some local markup to be repeated and `ng-template` allows that.

What is interesting is that it's even possible to pass a context to be able to use data binding:

```html
<ng-template #tplPerson let-person>
    <span class="person-id">{{person.id}}</span>
    <span class="person-alias" *ngIf="!!person.alias">"{{person.alias}}"</span>
    <span class="person-name">{{person.name}}</span>
</ng-template>
```

`let-person` without a value defines the context variable `person` with the value set to `$implicit` when instantiating the template:

```html
<ng-template *ngTemplateOutlet="tplPerson; context: {$implicit: thePerson}"></ng-template>
```

See more options in the documentation of [NgTemplateOutlet](https://angular.io/api/common/NgTemplateOutlet).

Comment: Excellent tip about pass a variable to the template, just what I need

Comment: This looks pretty similar to knockoutjs xD

Answer (score 33):

I might be late to the party.
There are some answers though, but I couldn't achieve it with what is described in above answers I still felt that someone might need a bit of direction.

Key points that are not defined in any of the answers clearly.

1. Consider you have a template which is binding some values in it. So you have to attach
   a context object in order make template binding work.

```html
<ng-template #invoicesTemplate let-paymentInvoices="paymentInvoices">
    ...
</ng-template>
```

note that let-anyVariableName for template and "paymentInvoices" is the class variable that you are passing.

in usage

```html
<ng-template *ngTemplateOutlet="invoicesTemplate; context: {paymentInvoices : paymentInvoices} "></ng-template>
```

2. You have to define template first and then use it anywhere you want to. Just think of
   a function declaration. But until unless you don't call function it wont have any affect.

Overall code
declaration of template

```html
<ng-template #invoicesTemplate let-paymentInvoices="paymentInvoices">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <div class="tags-group">
        <div class="tag" *ngFor="let invoice of paymentInvoices">
          <div class="tag-body">
            <span>{{invoice.invoiceNo }}</span>
            <span (click)="removeInvoice(invoice)"><i title="remove" >x</i></span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

calling/usage

```html
<ng-template *ngTemplateOutlet="invoicesTemplate; context: {paymentInvoices : paymentInvoices} "></ng-template>
```

You can use it any number of times you want.

Comment: maybe late, but really contributed well, your explanation was the most elaborate and understandable, this should be the top answer

Comment: working well in 2022

Answer (score 8):

You can create a custom html-tag using angular then import that component in your module that wants to use those custom-tags. Then you'll be allowed to use the same tag in your html page. Created a small example that can maybe help you understand ?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-stackoverflow

Comment: this method sadly means you can't use it a TemplateRef though

Comment: this is not what's asked. You have showcased how to reuse a component.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with help of a custom directive in a more standard way.

In `directive.ts`

```js
import { Directive } from '@angular/core';
@Directive({
  selector: '[cardItem]'
})
export class CardItemDirective {}
```

In `component.ts`

```js
import { Component, ContentChild, Input, TemplateRef } from '@angular/core';
import { CardItemDirective } from './card-item.directive';
import { ListItemDirective } from './list-item.directive';

@Component({
  selector: 'card-or-list-view',
  templateUrl: './card-or-list-view.component.html'
})
export class CardOrListViewComponent {

  @Input() items: any[] = [];

  @Input() mode: 'card' | 'list' = 'card';

  // Read in our structural directives as TemplateRefs
  @ContentChild(CardItemDirective, {read: TemplateRef}) cardItemTemplate;
  @ContentChild(ListItemDirective, {read: TemplateRef}) listItemTemplate;

}
```

in `component.html`

```html
<ng-container [ngSwitch]="mode">
<ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'card'">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let item of items">
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="cardItemTemplate"></ng-container>
  </ng-container>
</ng-container>
<ul *ngSwitchCase="'list'">
  <li *ngFor="let item of items">
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="listItemTemplate"></ng-container>
  </li>
</ul>
</ng-container>
```

You can find more details in [this link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/angular-reusable-components-ngtemplateoutlet)

Comment: When would you use this technique vs. just creating a component and re-using it in the same loop, as needed?