# How can I use same code in template without duplicate

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, typescript, angular2-template, code-duplication

Angular2 component. I want to show same code in modal after click on button.
How to use same HTML code in modal after click on button. Without duplication.

```
html code.
...
...
...
    <div class="modal fade" id="a" tabindex="-1" role="modal" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
same code here from above
...
...
...
```

Answer (score 1):

update to angular 5 and use ngTemplateOutletContext

```
    <template [ngTemplateOutlet]="templateRef">
    <div class="modal fade" id="a" tabindex="-1" role="modal" 
   aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
     <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="">
         <div class="modal-content">
   <div class="modal-header">
   </div>
   <div class="modal-body">
   </template>
```

**u can repeat the above code like below**

```
      <template  #templateRef></template>
```

**refer the link**
[How to repeat a piece of HTML multiple times without ngFor and without another @Component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37676593/how-to-repeat-a-piece-of-html-multiple-times-without-ngfor-and-without-another)

Answer (score 0):

say that you have two components: 
 - ChildComponent
 - ParentComponent

```
@Component({
  selector: 'child-selector',
  template: `...`,
})
export class ChildComponent {

}
```

then parent

```
@Component({
  selector: 'parent-selector',
  template: `
    <child-selector>
    </child-selector>
  `,
})
export class ParentComponent {
  public images: Images[] = [ ... ];

  }
}
```

you can check this link for detailed explaination: https://itnext.io/angular-patterns-2-how-to-write-seriously-reusable-components-96be16568abc